# javascript eval expression on undefined property

Tags: javascript, eval

I need to check if a formula passed by the user and using a restricted set of properties/values defined inside an object. The object properties are:

```
var klarf = {
   InspectedDiceCount: 0,
   FailedDiceCount: 0,
   PassedDiceCount: 0,
   UnclassifiedDiceCount: 0,
   InspectedDefectCount: 0,
   FailedDefectCount: 0,
   PassedDefectCount: 0,
   UnclassifiedDefectCount: 0
}
```

The user has to type any math expression returning a boolean value to consider the formula al "valid":

```
validate = eval(10 + klarf.PassedDiceCount > 100);  //returns false (but valid formula)
validate = eval(klarf.InspectedDiceCount > klarf.FailedDiceCount + 1); //return true (but valid formula)
```

how I can grab an error if the user specify an undefined property or undefined/unallowed variable?

```
validate = eval(10 + klarf.dummy > 0);    //returns true (but expected invalid formula)
validate = eval(a > b);
```

If not through eval are there any js libraries to perform formula evaluation?

The goal is to retrieve user formula typed in an `input text` form and then detect if:
a) Formula is valid (no matter if result is true or false) as it use only allowed variables. Valid formula are as example:

```
(klarf.InspectedDiceCount > 10)
(1 > 2)
((klarf.UnclassifiedDefectCount * 100 / klarf.InspectedDefectCount) > 0.1)
```

b) Formula is invalid as contains an undeclared variable or klarf object property. Invalid formula are as example:

```
klarf.PropertyThatDoesNotExists > 0
dummy_variable > 1
clarf.FailedDiceCount < 16
```

This is the js `validate` formula on which I'm working on:

```
function validate () {
    expr = "result = " + $('#rule_formula').val();
    r = eval(expr);
    console.log(expr, r, result);
    try {
        r = eval("result = " + $('#rule_formula').val());
    } catch(err) {
        $('#rule_validation').html("Invalid rule. Error (" + err.message + ") detected").css({
            'font-weight': 'bold',
            'color': 'red'
        });
    }
    if (typeof result == "boolean") {
        $('#rule_validation').html("Rule is valid").css({
            'font-weight': 'bold',
            'color': 'green'
        });
    } else {
        $('#rule_validation').html("Invalid rule. Boolean (true/false) output expected").css({
            'font-weight': 'bold',
            'color': 'red'
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: please specify the user input. is it a string?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong.

Comment: You don't need to use `eval()` to evaluate a boolean expression. Just `var y = 10 + obj.a > 100;` or `var y = (10 + obj.a) > 100;` will suffice.

Comment: @EdLucas, but how I then detect condition `var y = (10 + obj.z) > 100` as an error?
My goal is to distinguish "valid and true" condition from "valid and false" condition from "invalid" condition. And in this case `obj.z` is `NaN` and condition would not trigger the error (as I'm expecing)

Comment: Yes @NinaScholz, It's a string in an `input type='text'` box

Comment: It makes mores sense now that you've specified your input type. You could illustrate that  in your question with `validate = eval("10 + obj.a > 100")`. I expect that @NinaScholz will whip up an algorithm shortly.

Comment: @edlucas, I made an update to message putting the function on which I'm working on and the object used.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with [mathjs](https://mathjs.org/) evaluate method:

```
validate: function() {
    try {
        result = math.evaluate(
            $('#rule_formula').val(), {
            klarf: {
                InspectedDiceCount: 0,
                FailedDiceCount: 0,
                PassedDiceCount: 0,
                UnclassifiedDiceCount: 0,
                InspectedDefectCount: 0,
                FailedDefectCount: 0,
                PassedDefectCount: 0,
                UnclassifiedDefectCount: 0
            }
        });
        if (typeof result == "boolean") {
            $('#rule_validation').html("Valid rule detected").css({
                'color': 'green'
            });
        } else {
            $('#rule_validation').html("Invalid rule. Boolean (true/false) result expected").css({
                'color': 'red'
            });
        }
    } catch(err) {
        $('#rule_validation').html("Invalid rule. Error (" + err.message + ") detected").css({
            'color': 'red'
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if( obj.z ){
   validate = eval(10 + obj.z > 0);    //returns true (but expected invalid formula)
}else{
  // in valid formula 
}
```

Why not trying this ?

Comment: because I cannot predict what user will write. He can use 'obj.z' as long as 'whatever.foo' or 'invalid.variable' or (...) 
I basically need to consider a formula as "valid" if contains a boolean comparison and uses only the class defined properties. Otherwise it's invalid.

Comment: But then how are you using that in formula then ? like in formula `obj.z` but why not in if condition ?

Comment: I need to store the formula on a db (only if valid) and then to apply it on a set of files each of them containing different obj properties values. Then if formula is valid I allow the database storage. And if formula is valid && true I analyze the file. If formula is valid && false I reject it.